# Netsuite Subsidiaries - Bug creating quotes

Tags: rest, netsuite, suitescript, netsuite-rest-api

I'm currently trying to set up Netsuite OneWorld so I can enable subsidiaries on my Netsuite account. At the moment, I can create quotes on the Netsuite website fine from either subsidiary. The bug occurs when using a RESTlet function to create the quote, as it crashes with the following error:

```
data: '<error>\n' +
      '    <code>NEXUS_REQD</code>\n' +
      '    <message>No tax agency defined for subsidiary: subsidiary Global Voices Ltd (Parent Company) is not linked to nexus GB</message>\n' +
      '\n' +
      '    </error>\n'
```

Just to confirm - The script for this is NOT broken as it's currently being used in my production account without incident.

What I've tried:

- Creating a quote manually
- Using both subsidiaries
- Checking the Tax Agency, Subsidiary, Nexus, ec.

Comment: Yes, this is set up correctly...